# Yano-Bochner integral formula.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading Kobayashi's book transformations group in differential geometry and at the page 154 is this integral formula:

[image]

My question is how I can write a proof that is invariant i.e. index free? and how is the $(2)$ a corollary? I may need to know some additional properties about trace. Can some one fill in those details? It will help me a lot.

Comment: There is a typo in (2): it should be $+\frac12\operatorname{trace}((A_X+{^t\!A_X})^2)$.  The coordinates-free proof is the same -- show that $
\operatorname{div}(\nabla_XX-(\operatorname{div}X)X)
=\operatorname{Ric}(X,X)+\operatorname{trace}(A_XA_X)-(\operatorname{div}X)^2
$ using the intrinsic definition of div

Comment: @user10354138 How is the (2) a corollary?

Comment: trace here is just the usual trace of linear maps $T_xM\to T_xM$ at every point $x\in M$.  Recall $\operatorname{trace}(MN)=\operatorname{trace}(NM)$ for matrices $M,N\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.